# HTTP response after loading data

Tags: ajax, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I'd like to postpone the server response until the data using an Ajax request is loaded:

```
$.getJSON("xxx.json", function(result){
    $("#dataDiv").append(result['x'] + " ");
});
```

I'm using a simple HTML(JS) website. I'm testing it on the localhost, using a SimpleHTTPServer in Python.

However, when I send a `Get` request to the page, I get an empty "dataDiv". How can I postpone the server's HTTP response until the data is loaded?

Comment: How do you send `GET` request to the page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "postpone", but Ajax requests can be made synchronous (it's not recommended though.)

Comment: @Pekka, all I need is to see the data when I send a `Get` request

Comment: @towi_parallelism As far as I know Postman won't interpret your javascript, so you won't be able to see ajax output there.

Comment: Your async request looks right to me. I would put a `console.log(result);` as the first line of your 'success' function and make sure it is providing the result you are expecting.

Comment: I do get the result. I think the problem is more or less what @ArmanP. mentioned. I'm going to use this for an IoT project and my device has limited resources. It cannot run JavaScript, so I wanted to load the result via Ajax first and then send the HTTP response to the device. Seems like no doable!

Comment: @towi_parallelism Ajax request in javascript on it's own, so if it cannot run javascript, it cannot run ajax request from your code.

Comment: You r right! but I'd like to run it on server. So, maybe a Node.js solution might work?

Comment: I can load the data using an iframe (I just need to put a REST API's address as the source), but I still get nothing.. Can I make that work?

Comment: So in repsonse to an HTTP request from the device, you want to make an async request from the server , wait until the async request comes back and then feed the result as the HTTP response?

Comment: I think all I need is a proxy server. right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until the page is loaded then wrap the call in a document.ready callback.

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON("xxx.json", function(result){
      jQuery("#dataDiv").append(result['one'] + " ");
    });
  });
</script>
```